# Really deleting entries of MS Access database with ADODB command

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

I would like to delete rows of an access table. Therefore I am using VBA with an ADODB command object.

The problem is that instead of really deleting the row, the query just sets all values **except the ID** to 0 / ""

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do instead to really delete the entry?

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
Dim db1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim db_data As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

...'Code to build up Connection'

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.ActiveConnection = db1
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TableXY WHERE FieldXY = ValueXY"
Set db_data = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: Are you using the VBA within the same access DB ?

Comment: No, I am using it out of Visio

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly delete all:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM TableXY WHERE FieldXY = ValueXY"
```

You can also skip assigning it to a recordset: `cmd.Execute` instead of `Set db_data = cmd.Execute`.

Note that I can't replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

ValueXY must have a value:

```
ValueXY = SomeValue
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TableXY WHERE FieldXY = " & ValueXY & ""
```

or, if text:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TableXY WHERE FieldXY = '" & ValueXY & "'"
```

Comment: I'm assuming `ValueXY` is set, else you will get an _Invalid number of parameters error_, and not this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without using the command:

```
Dim db1 As New ADODB.Connection
db1.ConnectionString = "your connection string here"
db1.Open
db1.Execute "DELETE FROM TableXY WHERE FieldXY = ValueXY"
db1.Close
```

Comment: Please leave a comment for down voting if that is helpful.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, but you're answering an ADODB question (even one tagged specifically with [tag:adodb]) with a DAO answer, thus your answer isn't appropriate. There are many ways to delete rows, OP asks why this specific one doesn't work. You can comment that the question would be simpler using DAO, though

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - Thank you, i have just updated my answer.

Comment: Note that my assumption is that `ValueXY` is a parameter, and that's the reason OP uses a command object, and doesn't execute it directly (and also the reason why Gustavs answer is not valid). I might be wrong, though, since it isn't specified in the question.

Comment: Yes that's right. ValueXY is a Parameter. I should have specified that.